# Post textarea data with Jsoup

Tags: forms, post, textarea, jsoup

Currently, I'm trying to post some form data using Jsoup.
This works well for normal input type fields, but it doesn't for a textarea field.
Do you know, how to post textarea data with Jsoup?

My html form would look something like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="input1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="input2">
    <textarea name="input3"></textarea>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

My Jsoup Code would look something like this:

```
Response response = Jsoup.connect(URL)
                    .method(Method.POST)
                    .data("input1", "something")
                    .data("input2", "something else")
                    .data("input3", "textarea content")
                    .execute();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In what way is it not working for you? What is your response code? I can't reproduce the problem:

using a [w3schools echo form](http://www.w3schools.com/php/demo_form_validation_complete.php) the textarea is set as intended:

```
try {
    Response response = Jsoup.connect("http://www.w3schools.com/php/demo_form_validation_complete.php").method(Method.POST).data("name", "some name").data("email","mail@mail.com").data("comment", "some test input in textarea").data("gender", "male").execute();
    System.out.println(response.body().toString());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output (excerpt):

```
<h2>Your Input:</h2>some name<br>mail@mail.com<br><br>some test input in textarea<br>male
```

Comment: Yes, it works correctly. I figured out, that the target website is build of javascript after pageload. So it didn't behave as aspected, when I parsed it with Jsoup.